# c++ how can i access virtual method in a template class which will be overriden in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overriding, virtual

I have a templated `Base` class with 2 virtual methods `begin()` and `end()`.

I also have `Derived1` class derived from `Base` class, and
`Derived2` class derived from `Derived1` class.

I am overriding method `begin()` in first derived class, and method `end()` in second derived class.

But I cannot access/use the method `end()` in my first derived class. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base {
public:
    virtual T begin() = 0;

    virtual T end() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T> {
public:
    T begin() override {
        return Base<T>::end() - 10;     // not working
        // return end() - 10;           // also not working
    }
};

template <class T>
class Derived2 : public Derived1<T> {
public:
    T end() override {
        return 10;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived2<int> derived2;
    std::cout << derived2.begin() << "\n";
    std::cout << derived2.end() << "\n";
}
```

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl Base<int>::end(void)" (?end@?$Base@H@@UEAAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl Derived1<int>::begin(void)" (?begin@?$Derived1@H@@UEAAHXZ)

Comment: A quick test on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bEWaj4zbc) shows it working fine. Which compiler and flags are you using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it includes the whole error message, don't put that info into comments.

Comment: @Quentin how can that be? `Base` is an abstract base class with pure virtual methods. The derived classes are still abstract and not concrete. Instantiating an abstract class will throw compile errors.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon `Derived2` does end up implementing both functions, so it is not abstract. The reason I did not reproduce OP's error before they quoted it is that Godbolt.org does not link by default. The actual error is that `Base::end()` explicitly references `Base`'s implementation of `end`, which *is* a thing you can do even with pure virtual functions, but which doesn't actually exist here.

Answer (score 0):

`Base::begin()` and `Base::end()` are pure-virtual methods. You cannot use them because they have no definition.

```cpp
return Base<T>::end() - 10; /* Will not work and will bring about compile errors.*/
```

Either provide a definition in `Base` or provide one in `Derived1` and use that instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Base {
public:
    virtual T begin() = 0;
    virtual T end() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T> {
public:
    T begin() override {
        return this->end() - 10;  // Access end() from the immediate base class
    }
};

template <class T>
class Derived2 : public Derived1<T> {
public:
    T end() override {
        return 10;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived2<int> derived2;
    std::cout << derived2.begin() << "\n";
    std::cout << derived2.end() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. Youhave to explain.

Comment: The comment on the `begin()` implementation is wrong: `this->end()` does _not_ really access the version from the base class: it find the version in the base class but doesn't really call it. That wouldn't work anyway as the base class doesn't have an implementation. However, `end()` isn't a dependent name and `this->` provides the dependency, causing `end()` to be looked up in class scope. It find the base class name which is a `virtual` function, causing the approprivate override to be called.